Backtest results differ from real entry and exit signals
The backtest results differ from the actual entry and exit signals.
I use the functions calc_on_every_tick, calc_on_order_fills and use_bar_magnifier.
The strategy has an exit through SL or TP.
But TP uses TSL.
The problem is that when launching a strategy, the backtest results differ greatly from real transactions on the exchange. Please tell me if something can be done so that the backtest does not recolor and shows real entries and exits inside the bar. Thank you!
//@version=5
strategy("ХХХ", overlay=true)

from_day = input.int(defval=1, title='From Day', minval=1)
from_month = input.int(defval=3, title='From Month', minval=1)
from_year = input.int(defval=2018, title='From Year', minval=1970)

to_day = input.int(defval=1, title='To Day', minval=1)
to_month = input.int(defval=1, title='To Month', minval=1)
to_year = input.int(defval=2100, title='To Year', minval=1970)

time_cond = time > timestamp(from_year, from_month, from_day, 00, 00) and time < timestamp(to_year, to_month, to_day, 23, 59)






ma_type = input.string('EMA', 'MA Type', ['ALMA','HMA','SMA','SWMA','VWMA','WMA','ZLEMA','EMA'], group = 'Setup')
ma_period = input.int(9, 'MA Period (Length)', 1, group='Setup')

alma_offset = input.float(0.85, 'ALMA Shift', 0, 1, 0.05, group = 'Setup (ALMA)')
alma_sigma = input.int(6, 'ALMA Deviation', 1, step = 1, group = 'Setup (ALMA)')

show_line_1(x) =>
    input.bool(true, 'Show Close line', group = 'On/Off') ? x : na
show_line_2(x) =>
    input.bool(false, 'Show High/Low lines', group = 'On/Off') ? x : na
show_fill(x) =>
    input.bool(true, 'Show fill', group = 'On/Off') ? x : na
//╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
//║ Calculations :
f(x) =>
    switch ma_type
        'ALMA' => ta.alma(x, ma_period, alma_offset, alma_sigma)
        'HMA' => ta.hma(x, ma_period)
        'SMA' => ta.sma(x, ma_period)
        'SWMA' => ta.swma(x)
        'VWMA' => ta.vwma(x, ma_period)
        'WMA' => ta.vwma(x, ma_period)
        'ZLEMA' => ta.ema(x + x - x[math.floor((ma_period - 1) / 2)], ma_period)
        => ta.ema(x, ma_period)

ma_heikinashi_open = f(request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open))
ma_heikinashi_close = f(request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close))
ma_heikinashi_high = f(request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high))
ma_heikinashi_low = f(request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low))

trend = 100 * (ma_heikinashi_close - ma_heikinashi_open) / (ma_heikinashi_high - ma_heikinashi_low)
//╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
//║ Colors :
color_positive = input.color(color.new(#26A69A, 0), 'Positive color (Bullish)', group = 'Colors')
color_negative = input.color(color.new(#EF5350, 0), 'Negative color (Bearish)', group = 'Colors')
color_neutral = input.color(color.new(#808080, 0), 'Neutral color', group = 'Colors')

color_trend = trend > 0 ? color_positive : color_negative
//╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
//║ Plot :
plot_open = plot(ma_heikinashi_open, 'Open line', na)
plot_close = plot(ma_heikinashi_close, 'Close line', show_line_1(color_trend), 2)
plot_high = plot(ma_heikinashi_high, 'High line', show_line_2(color_neutral))
plot_low = plot(ma_heikinashi_low, 'Low line', show_line_2(color_neutral))

plot_highest = plot(math.max(ma_heikinashi_open, ma_heikinashi_close),'Highest Body line', na)
plot_lowest = plot(math.min(ma_heikinashi_open, ma_heikinashi_close),'Lowest Body line', na)
//╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
//║ Fill :
fill(plot_open, plot_close, color.new(color_trend,50), 'Open/Close Cloud')
fill(plot_high, plot_highest, show_fill(color.new(color_neutral,87.5)), title = 'High Cloud')
fill(plot_lowest, plot_low, show_fill(color.new(color_neutral,87.5)), title = 'Low Cloud')
//╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝


// Look for moving average crosses
crossAbove = trend>0
crossUnder = trend<0

if crossAbove and time_cond and strategy.position_size == 0
    color.new(color.green, 80)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long , comment = "LONG"  )
    
else if crossUnder and time_cond and strategy.position_size == 0
    color.new(color.red, 80)
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short , comment = "SORT"  )  







stoploss = input.float( 2 , "Stop Loss percentage" , minval= 0 )

takeprofit = input.float( 2 , "Take Profit percentage" , minval= 0 )

trailingstop = input(true , "Trailing Stop")
trail_p = input.float( 0.05 , "Trailing Stop percentage (of entry price)" , minval= 0 )




av_p = strategy.position_avg_price

if trailingstop 
    
    if strategy.position_size > 0 and strategy.position_size[1] <= 0

        mes_pa = "   start trail: "+str.tostring(   av_p + (av_p *  takeprofit/100)    ) +"\n trail offset: "+ str.tostring( av_p *(trail_p/100)   ) +"\n SL: "+ str.tostring( av_p - (av_p *  stoploss/100)    ) 

        label.new(bar_index, low - low *(trail_p/100) , mes_pa , style = label.style_label_up , color = color.white ,textcolor = color.black, size = size.normal)

    else if  strategy.position_size < 0 and strategy.position_size[1] >= 0

        mes_pa = "   start trail: "+str.tostring(   av_p - (av_p *  takeprofit/100)    ) +"\n trail offset: "+ str.tostring(   av_p *(trail_p/100)     )  +"\n SL: "+ str.tostring( av_p + (av_p *  stoploss/100)    ) 
        
        label.new(bar_index, high + high *(trail_p/100) , mes_pa , style = label.style_label_down  , color = color.white ,textcolor = color.black, size = size.normal)





    
    strategy.exit("exit_buy", "long" ,  when= strategy.position_size > 0  ,  stop  =  av_p - (av_p *  stoploss/100)  ,  trail_price = av_p + (av_p *  takeprofit/100) , trail_offset = av_p *(trail_p/100) *1/syminfo.mintick  , comment = "EXIT LONG1" ) 
    
    strategy.exit("exit_sell", "short" ,when= strategy.position_size < 0,  stop  =  av_p + (av_p *  stoploss/100),  trail_price = av_p - (av_p *  takeprofit/100) , trail_offset = av_p *(trail_p/100) *1/syminfo.mintick  , comment = "EXIT SHORT1") 

    

else



    strategy.exit("exit_buy", "long" ,  when= strategy.position_size > 0 ,  stop  =  av_p - (av_p *  stoploss/100)  ,  limit  =  av_p + (av_p *  takeprofit/100) , comment = "EXIT LONG2" ) 
    
    strategy.exit("exit_sell", "short" ,when= strategy.position_size < 0 ,  stop  =  av_p + (av_p *  stoploss/100)   ,  limit  =  av_p - (av_p *  takeprofit/100) , comment = "EXIT SHORT2") 


Hi. Your strategy uses heikin ashi. About Backtesting on Non-Standard Charts

The problem is not this. Even if I change the entry/exit analysis block on moving averages, the situation is as follows, the signal to the TP comes at 07:41:11, the asset price at this moment is, say, 205.44, the exchange position is closed at a price of 205 ,44, and in the backtest the closing price was 205.96, the price was 205.96 at 07:44:35.
What can be done to ensure that the closing price is the one at which the transaction was actually closed?
